# Custom TextInput component loses focus but still contains cursor?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4.5

I have a custom `TextInput` that listens for the `FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN` and `FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT` events:

```
textDisplay.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocusInHandler);
textDisplay.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT, onFocusOutHandler);
```

My `onFocusInHandler` function basically removes a "promptview" that tells the user to type in a value, with the `onFocusOutHandler` doing the opposite.

For example, if the TextInput text was backspaced to a blank value and the user clicks out of the TextInput box, it would show a "Please enter a value" light-gray prompt in the TextInput.

This works fine until the user clicks our custom "Clear" button.  The clear button sets the text to "", and I can tell the `FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT` is received because the prompt text is set to visible (its not being set anywhere else).  The problem is, the cursor remains in the box as if it still has focus, so if the user immediately starts typing, both the prompt text "Please enter a value" *and* the user-entered text appears over the gray text, which looks pretty ugly and unreadable.

Why does the TextInput receive the `FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT` event if it's not actually losing focus?  Is there any way I can get around this?

Comment: Are you disabling the component?  My experience is that the Spark TextInput doesn't properly make the visual changes it should when it loses focus if it's disabled.

Comment: Are you using the Spark TextInput or the MX TextInput?  Doesn't the spark TextInput do this by default?  Just use the prompt property. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/SkinnableTextBase.html#prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1. Use the Spak TextInput in Flex 4.1 or 4.5. This already provides a promptDisplay by default (as mentioned in the comments)

Option 2. Take a look at the focus-skin. This skin class is usually placed on top of the normal skin. There could exist some focus ambiguity between these two. Try using a custom focus-skin without a textDisplay and clear button.

Option 3. Not only use a focus event to show or hide the prompt, but also look at the content of the TextInput. You don't want to display a prompt when the text is set by binding as wel.

Comment: I switched to the Spark TextInput.  I was hesitant because we had other components that relied on our custom one, but if its available it makes more sense to just change.  Thanks!